# How to remove "," in foreach()?

Tags: php

I have a code php

```
foreach ($cities as $city) {
     echo substr($city->name . ", ", 0, -2);
}
```

> result is: a, b, c, d, e,

How to remove "," in foreach()

> Exactly: a, b, c, d, e

Comment: take values in string and at last remove last `,` from the string. other logic is also there but it will be a overhead for such small task

Answer (score 8):

You could achieve the same with less code, by using the [implode](http://php.net/implode) function.

```
$comma_separated = implode(',', $cities);
```

Should give you exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '';
foreach ($cities as $city){
    $str .= "$city, ";
}
$str = rtrim($str, " ,");
```

Answer (score 1):

In this context you can not remove the last comma without additional tags.

You have two other options:

**1. Use the standard for loop**:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($cities)-1; $i++) {
    echo $cities[$i]->name . ", ";
}
echo $cities(count($cities)-1)->name;
```

**2. Create a result string in the foreach**, remove the last character and than print it.

Answer (score 1):

<del>Just do :-</del>

<del>`echo implode(',', $cites);`</del>

<del>That will give you your desired output.</del>
I just noticed from your code that `$cities` is an object not an array, sorry:-

```
foreach($cities as $city){
    $cityNames[] = $city->name;
}
echo implode(',', $cityNames);
```

http://www.php.net/implode

Answer (score 0):

```
$first = true;
foreach ($cities as $city) {
    if( !$first ){
        echo ', ';
    }else{
        $first = false;
    }
    echo $city->name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it a bit to something like:

```
$first = TRUE;

foreach ( $cities as $city )
{
    if ( !$first )
    {
        echo( "," );
    }

    $first = FALSE;
    echo( $city->name );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [rtrim](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) after the `foreach()`:

```
$city->name = rtrim($city->name,',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 :

```
$index = 0;
    foreach ($cities as $city) {
    $index++;
    echo $city->name . ($index == count($cities)?"":",");

    }
```

Method 2:

```
$str = "";
    foreach ($cities as $city) {
    $str .=  $city->name . ",";    
    }
$str = substr_replace($str ,"",-1);
echo $str;
```

Comment: I think we can't use implode here if the array has other values as well. What if $city->postalCode also exists in the array.